# Travis CI not sending Jacoco reports to SonarCloud

Tags: github, code-coverage, travis-ci, jacoco, sonarcloud

I have a Spring Boot project repository on Github with Travis CI integrated. Currently Travis CI is configured to build the project for commits and Pull requests, which works fine.

Next, I want to send a Jacoco report to SonarCloud. I have followed the wiki on Travis but when I look at SoundCloud project nothing is shown. Following is my configuration:

1. *Authentication token for `SonarCloud` account*: I have generated it on *SonarCloud* and set it in `Travis -> Environment Variables -> SONAR_TOKEN`.
2. *.travis.yml*

   ```
   script: 
     - mvn install -P test
     - mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:report package sonar:sonar

   addons:
     sonarcloud:
       organization: "my_organization_name_on_SonarCloud"
   ```
3. Project's *src/main/resources/sonar-project.properties*

   ```
   sonar.projectKey=my_project_key_on_SonarCloud
   sonar.projectName=my_project_name
   sonar.projectVersion=0.0.1
   sonar.sources=.
   ```
4. *Jacoco-maven-plugin*

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
       <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>0.8.3</version>
       <executions>
           <execution>
               <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
               <goals>
                   <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
               </goals>
               </execution>
           <execution>
               <id>default-report</id>
               <phase>prepare-package</phase>
               <goals>
                   <goal>report</goal>
               </goals>
           </execution>
       </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```

Following are the Travis CI Job logs

```
Setting environment variables from repository settings
$ export SONAR_TOKEN=[secure]
SonarCloud addon
addon hash: de356982c12b370c7bfe9c5317053863
Preparing SonarQube Scanner CLI
Archive:  /home/travis/.sonarscanner/sonar-scanner.zip
inflating: /home/travis/.sonarscanner/sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778/bin/sonar-scanner-debug.bat  
inflating: /home/travis/.sonarscanner/sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778/bin/sonar-runner.bat  
inflating: /home/travis/.sonarscanner/sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778/bin/sonar-scanner.bat  
inflating: /home/travis/.sonarscanner/sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778/bin/sonar-runner  
inflating: /home/travis/.sonarscanner/sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778/bin/sonar-scanner  
inflating: /home/travis/.sonarscanner/sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778/bin/sonar-scanner-debug  
creating: /home/travis/.sonarscanner/sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778/conf/
inflating: /home/travis/.sonarscanner/sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778/conf/sonar-scanner.properties  
creating: /home/travis/.sonarscanner/sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778/lib/
inflating: /home/travis/.sonarscanner/sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778/lib/sonar-scanner-cli-3.0.3.778.jar  
$ export SONAR_SCANNER_HOME=${TRAVIS_HOME}/.sonarscanner/sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778
Not installing SonarSource build-wrapper because it's a Java or Javascript project
Preparing SonarQube Scanner parameters0.00s
$ 
The command "" exited with 0.
```

Can somebody point out what I am missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

script:
- mvn clean install -B
- mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=...

sudo: required
addons:
  sonarcloud:
    organization: ...
    token:
      secure: $SONAR_TOKEN

Could you try like above